# Trouble working with `requestBody` (or `getRequestBodyChunk`)

Tags: haskell, scotty, haskell-wai

### Dependency versions

- Wai: `3.2.2.1`

### Synopsis

The working of `getRequestBodyChunk` (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.2.2.1/docs/Network-Wai.html#v:getRequestBodyChunk) is quite unclear to me. I understand that it reads the next chunk of bytes available in a request; and finally yields a `Data.ByteString.empty` indicating no more bytes are available.

Thus, given a `req :: Request`; I'm trying to create a `Conduit` from the request body as:

```hs
streamBody :: Wai.Request -> ConduitM () ByteString IO ()
streamBody req = repeatWhileMC (Wai.getRequestBodyChunk) (Data.ByteString.empty /=)
```

However, this seems to terminate immediately, as I've seen tracing the outputs:

```hs
repeatWhileMC (traceShowId <$> Wai.getRequestBodyChunk req) (traceShowId . (Data.ByteString.empty /=))
```

The output is

```
""
False
```

And hence the stream terminates.

But I can verify that the request body is not empty by other means.

So I'm a little stumped about this and I have a few questions:

- Does this mean that the request body has been already consumed?
- Or does this mean that the request body wasn't chunked?
- Or does it mean that for smaller requests; the chunked bytes are always empty?
- Is Scotty overriding this especially for smaller sized requests (I cannot seem to find this anywhere in its code/docs.)
- If I do something like this:

```hs
streamBody req = 
  let req' = req { requestBody = pure "foobar" }
  in repeatWhileMC (Wai.getRequestBodyChunk req') (Data.ByteString.empty /=)
```

I do get a non terminating stream of bytes; which leads me to suspect that something before this part of the code consumes the request body: or that function returns an empty body to begin with.

A point to note is that this seems to happen with smaller requests only.

Another point to note that I get the `Wai.Request` via `Web.Scotty.Trans.request`; which also has the body related streaming helpers.

Can this also be documented? I believe the documentation for `getRequestBodyChunk` etc. can be improved with this information.

Comment: In my experience, working with Wai's treatment of request bodies has been a source of problems for me. It introduces a huge source of non-idempotency: you have to be very careful not to call `strictRequestBody`, `getRequestBodyChunk` etc. anywhere else, and hope that no middleware etc. calls it before your consumer function. 
This makes it a very big source of pain. In fact, writing an HTTP API Gateway has been hell with this.